# Text/font size in Div different in print mode in Firefox than in "normal" mode

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, printing

Situation is as follows: I made a tool allowing a user to create flashcards (stored in a mysql-library). Now if you want to print the flashcards, the script generates a table in which the td's have a fixed width (in px), inside is a div containing the user-entered text for the front or backside of the flashcard. Since the amount of text can vary, the standard font-size is reduced if necessary. Looks like that:

```
HTML:
<table class="cardtable">
    <tr>
        <td class="cardtd wrap"><div class="adjustsize"> 
                  Shorter Text here in the first td
            </div></td>
        <td class="cardtd wrap"><div class="adjustsize"> 
                  Might be a loooooooooooooooong text here in the second td
            </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>


CSS:
table.cardtable {
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    page-break-before:always;
}

td.cardtd {
    width: 470px;
    max-width: 470px;
    height:300px;
    max-height:300px;
    font-size:11px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-left:22px;
    padding-right:22px;
}

td.wrap { /*if a word is too long -> break it */
    white-space: pre;           /* CSS 2.0 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line;      /* CSS 3.0 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
    white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;  /* HP Printers */
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5+ */
}

div.adjustsize {
   display:block;
   max-width:inherit;
   max-height:inherit;
   font-size:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:center; 
}


Js:
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('div.adjustsize').each(function() {
            var fontSize = 100;
            while (this.scrollHeight > $(this).height() && fontSize > 0) {
                fontSize -= 0.2;
                $(this).css('font-size', fontSize + '%');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So now my big problem is: When I let the script render the table in Firefox, the JS adjusts the size of the font correctly, meaning that if a text is too long at first, the JS reduces the font size until it fits the div. But if I want to print the page afterwards, in the print-mode of firefox the text suddenly exceeds the div, meaning that a part of it is not visible anymore (scaling 100%)!

PS: I chose the width and height of the td to fit it more or less on a A4 sheet of paper.

EDIT:
Thanks for the suggestions. I tried using the @media css styles and I checked every css value I could imagine with the window.onbeforeprint and window.onafterprint function to see if anything somehow changed but nothing. Every value including padding, margin, letter-spacing, etc. is exactly the same as before, yet when I press "print" in Firefox, the preview somewhat compresses/narrows some elements causing the text to take up more lines. Strangely, when using some plugins in Firefox that allows you to edit code in print mode that plugin displays the rendered elements correctly.

Concluding, the problem seems somehow only to occur in print preview (and the actual printing later) but I cannot find a corresponding "error" or mismatch in the code.

I read a couple of articles about dpi, is it possible that the print preview uses a different dpi from my browser because it is trying to imitate/preview a printer (which have a different dpi than screens) ?

Answer (score 1):

check this link [link](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/)

```
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        console.log('onbeforeprint equivalent');
    } else {
        console.log('onafterprint equivalent');
    }
});
```

or

```
 var beforePrint = function() {
               //your code 
            };
            var afterPrint = function() {
              //your code 
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a print css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your file css here .css" media="print" />
```